# Finding the project dir from within a CocoaPods podspec file

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to write a CocoaPods podspec file which needs to work on the `xcodeproj` file from within a `prepare_command` and therefore needs to know where the `xcodeproj` resides.
I was wondering whether there was some way (some API) to retrieve the directory of the project for which we're running `pod install`. In other words - the directory from which we ran `pod install`.

I found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/niklasberglund/4534113ce7db9572e772), however it assumes the pod exists under the project's dir, which is not always the case (e.g. if using `:path ==>` in the podfile).
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Ariel